# dplyr: mutate nested group doesn't work as expected

Tags: r, grouping, dplyr

I would like to group a list of numbers depending on whether they are even and count the even and odd groups.

```r
suppressPackageStartupMessages(library(dplyr))

even <- function(x) return(! x %% 2)

df   <- group_nest(tibble(x = 1:9), even=even(x))
```

This works:

```
# A tibble: 2 x 2
  even                data
  <lgl> <list<tbl_df[,1]>>
1 FALSE            [5 x 1]
2 TRUE             [4 x 1]
```

Now I want to add a third column with the count of the groups

```r
mutate(df, count=nrow(data))
```

I would expect the following result:

```
# A tibble: 2 x 3
  even                data  count
  <lgl> <list<tbl_df[,1]>> <int>
1 FALSE            [5 x 1]      5
2 TRUE             [4 x 1]      4
>
```

Although, the actual result is the same as the original dataframe, no column added, no error, nothing.

Manual checking:

```
nrow(df[[2]][[1]])
[1] 5

nrow(df[[2]][[2]])
[1] 4
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

can be used

```
mutate(df, count=map_dbl(data, nrow))

# A tibble: 2 x 3
  even                data count
  <lgl> <list<tbl_df[,1]>> <dbl>
1 FALSE            [5 x 1]     5
2 TRUE             [4 x 1]     4
```

Comment: I've accepted this as the answer. Can you explain what was wrong with my attempt? Did I operate on the list but not on the dataframe/tibble level? Why was there no error or warning indicating that something went wrong?

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot explain the technical details. In my understanding, if there is a list at the input, then the list function should handle it, for example `map_dbl`